# Sense of using NTP client on Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, ntp

What is the sense of using NTP clients on Kubernetes (k8s) pods while the time is propagated from the host os?

Many tutorials are showing how to host NTP and sync pods, but in other topics I found information that the time on pods is taken from the host os. Can anyone advise if there is any sense in syncing pods with NTP? Will it even make any change - I assume that pods are isolated from host os and it will get overridden.

I'm not asking about custom timezones in pods - that is something different.